# I can't program a pause based on a condition

Tags: android, countdowntimer, pause

I am making an app that will pause a countdown timer when a specific condition exists.  My countdown timer cycles through a string-array to populate text fields.  Each time the counter gets down to zero, it resets and populates the text fields with the next set of text.  I even have a working pause button.  However, I can't program-matically pause the countdown timer based on specific text in one of the text fields.

Heres my timer code:

```
class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    //constructor for timer class
    public MyTimer(long millisInFurture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFurture, countDownInterval);
    }

    // this method called when timer is finished
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // reset all variables
        clockText.setText(clockTime);
        isRunning = false;
        remainMilli = 0;

        advanceLevel();
        goTimer();
    }

    // this method is called for every iteration of time interval
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        remainMilli = millisUntilFinished;

        //calculate minutes and seconds from milliseconds
        String minute = "" + (millisUntilFinished/1000)/60;
        String second = "" + (millisUntilFinished/1000)%60;

        // apply style to minute and second
        if((millisUntilFinished/1000)/60 < 10) {
            minute = "0" + (millisUntilFinished/1000)/60;
        }
        if ((millisUntilFinished/1000)%60 < 10) {
            second = "0" + (millisUntilFinished/1000)%60;
        }

        //update textview with remaining time
        clockText.setText(minute + ":" + second);
    }

}
```

Here's my Start and Pause code for the timer:

```
public boolean goTimer() {
    breakCheck = blinds.getText().toString();
    Log.i(breakCheck, "level");

    if (isRunning) {
        // cancel (Pause) timer when it is running
        mTimer.cancel();
        mTimer = null;
        isRunning = false;
    } else {
        if (remainMilli == 0) {
            // start timer from initial time
            mTimer = new MyTimer(blindTime, 1000);

        } else {
            //resume timer from where it is paused
            mTimer = new MyTimer(remainMilli, 1000);
        }
        mTimer.start();
        isRunning = true;
        }

    return true;

}
```

...and here is the code that changes the text fields after each loop of the countdown timer:

```
public boolean advanceLevel() {
    levelNum = levelNum + 1;
    round = round + 1;
    anteLevel = anteLevel + 1;

    if (round < roundMax) {
        level.setText(String.valueOf(levelNum));
        blinds.setText(blinds_list[round]);
        ante.setText(ante_list[anteLevel]);
    } else if (round == roundMax) {
        level.setText("Max Level");

    } else if (round > roundMax) {
        try {
            mTimer.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So every time the countdown finishes, the text fields get populated with new text from the String-array.  What I want is for when the blinds text field is showing "BREAK", I want the countdown timer to pause.

So, I put in a:

```
String blindCheck = blinds.getText().toString();
```

if (blindCheck == "BREAK") { mTimer.cancel(); }

...but no matter what I do, the countdown timer doesn't pause, it just keeps going.

The Start/Pause button for the timer is on the bottom nav bar, and works great, so when my blindCheck == "BREAK", I tried having it execute the method to Start/Pause the clock, but that didn't work either.

I'm not sure what to do here.  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Hendo

Answer (score 0):

Do not use CountDownTimer for this Purpose. Instead of this, you should use Handler like this

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // done your functionality here


            // if you want to continue, or pause is not active
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1*1000);

            // else you will in pause state

        }
    };


    // to start the hanlder
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1*1000);

    // to stop or pause the handler
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: So I'm to wipe out everything that I have in place now?  Is that because it can't be done with what I have, or is it because using handler is just a better way to go?  Because everything that I have now works just fine...except for making it pause during a certain event.  Thanks, Hendo.

Comment: I am giving you a batterway

Comment: Well, this way works as well, but I still can't get it to pause automatically when the text field says BREAK.

Comment: Just make a condition in run(). `if (!textView.getText().toString().equals("BREAK"))
 handler.postDelayed(this, 1*1000);`

Comment: When this is equal to BREAK. it will not repeat itself